# Drag and Drop Arrays AS3

Tags: arrays

I'm trying to create a drag and drop game in Actionscript 3 using mostly arrays. I'm doing it on a simpler game first before going to the main game because I need to know how the codes work first.

The simpler game is just there are two squares and two circles. The two squares are on a different array while the two circles are in the same one. What should happen is that when either circles hit (hitTestPoint) the right square, their x and y becomes the center of the square. (like it clicks to the center). And when either circles hit the left square, it should return the circles to their last position (doesn't have to be their original position).

Here's the code:

package 
{

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.display.DisplayObject;
import flash.geom.Point;
import flash.events.Event;


public class MC_MAIN extends MovieClip
{

    var mc1:mc_circle;
    var mc2:mc_circle;
    var mc3:mc_square;
    var mc4:mc_square;
    var Shapes:Array;
    var Target:Array;
    var WTarget:Array;

    var newPlace:Point;

    public function MC_MAIN()
    {
        // constructor code

        init();
    }

    function init():void
    {
        Shapes = new Array  ;
        Target = new Array  ;
        WTarget = new Array  ;

        mc3 = new mc_square();
        mc3.height = 75;
        mc3.width = 75;
        mc3.x = 400;
        mc3.y = 200;
        Target.push(mc3);
        addChild(mc3);

        mc4 = new mc_square();
        mc4.height = 75;
        mc4.width = 75;
        mc4.x = 150;
        mc4.y = 200;
        WTarget.push(mc4);
        addChild(mc4);

        mc1 = new mc_circle();
        mc1.height = 25;
        mc1.width = 25;
        mc1.x = 100;
        mc1.y = 100;
        Shapes.push(mc1);
        addChild(mc1);

        mc2 = new mc_circle();
        mc2.height = 25;
        mc2.width = 25;
        mc2.x = 200;
        mc2.y = 200;
        Shapes.push(mc2);
        addChild(mc2);

        for (var i:int = 0; i<Shapes.length; i++)
        {
            Shapes[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, DRG);
            Shapes[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, SDRG);
        }
    }

    function DRG(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        e.currentTarget.startDrag();
    }

    function SDRG(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        e.currentTarget.stopDrag();

        for (var m:int = 0; m<Shapes.length; m++)
        {
            newPlace = new Point(Shapes[m].x,Shapes[m].y);
        }
        trace(newPlace);

        for (var a:int = 0; a<Target.length; a++)
        {
            for (var b:int = 0; b<Shapes.length; b++)
            {
                if (Target[a].hitTestPoint(Shapes[b].x,Shapes[b].y))
                {
                    Shapes[b].x = Target[a].x;
                    Shapes[b].y = Target[a].y;
                }
            }
        }

        for (var c:int = 0; c<WTarget.length; c++)
        {
            for (var d:int = 0; d<Shapes.length; d++)
            {
                if (WTarget[c].hitTestPoint(Shapes[d].x,Shapes[d].y))
                {
                    Shapes[d].x = newPlace.x;
                    Shapes[d].y = newPlace.y;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

What happens is that the code for the left square doesn't work but their are no syntax errors. Nothing happens when either circles hit the left square.

And when I'm trying to trace the position of the circles, It just shows the x & y coordinate of only one of them. (I guess it's tracing the first object of the array which is at index 0. I'm just asking if I guessed right for this part.)

Answer (score 0):

I is a bit difficult to follow the logic and there are some points that doesn't make much sense like:

```
for (var m:int = 0; m<Shapes.length; m++)
{
  newPlace = new Point(Shapes[m].x,Shapes[m].y);
}
```

`newPlace` will be the position of the last `shape` in `Shapes`, so the loop is fairly useless.

I guess what you need is something like that:

```
public class MC_MAIN extends MovieClip
{
  private leftSquares:Array;
  private rightSquares:Array;
  //more of the members from above
  private startPos:Point;

  //init the thing and add left and right squares
  //to there respective Array

  function DRG(e:MouseEvent):void
  {
    var t:DisplayObject = e.currentTarget;
    //save the starting position
    startPos = new Point(t.x,t.y);
    t.startDrag();
  }

  function SDRG(e:MouseEvent):void {
    var t:DisplayObject = e.currentTarget;

    //find all squares from the left
    //the target »hits«
    var leftHits:Array = leftSquares.filter(
     function (square:DisplayObject) {
       return square.hitTestPoint(t.x, t.y);
     });


    //same for the right
    var leftHits:Array = rightSquares.filter(
     function (square:DisplayObject) {
       return square.hitTestPoint(t.x, t.y);
     });

     //now you can apply the logic
     //based on the hit Test result
     //this way you can handle the case
     //if it hits both, to throw an error
     //or alike
     if(leftHits.length > 0) {
       //reset position
       t.x = startPos.x;
       t.y = startPos.y;
     }

     else if (rightHits.length > 0) {
       //set the position tp the desired item in rightHits
     }

     else {

     }
  }
}
```

Please not that my Action Script skills haven't been used for a long time, so the code above might not compile. It is meant to illustrate the idea. Important are the following steps:

```
1. Save the starting position, to be able to reset it
2. Sort the `squares` in respective lists for left and right
3. Hit test both and apply the logic.
```

Comment: I think i get what you are saying. Thanks a lot, I've revised my code a bit and it's working fine. Thanks for the tips.

Comment: your welcome, feel free to accept if it solves the issues…